# How can I use a default value for this array? The result is not displayed until the first loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, setinterval

I have this code:

```
<span id="changeText"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var text = ["cool", "awesome", "outstanding"];
        var counter = 0;
        var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
        var refreshIntervalI = setInterval(change, 2000);

        function change() 
        {
           elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
           counter++;
           if (counter >= text.length) { clearInterval(refreshIntervalI); }
        }

  </script>
```

The output correctly displays each word after 2000ms, but it also takes 2sec to display the first word. How can I set a default value which will be displayed until the start of the loop?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just like this

```
    var text = ["cool", "awesome", "outstanding"];

    var counter = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    elem.innerHTML = text[0];
    var refreshIntervalI = setInterval(change, 2000);

    function change() 
    {
       elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
       counter++;
       if (counter >= text.length) { clearInterval(refreshIntervalI); }
    }
```

Set the first value of your array as `innerHTML` on load and let the counter start at `1` and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the function without setInterval() for the first time:

```
function change() {
  ...
}
change();
```